# "Failed to extract MSVCP140.dll: decompression resulted in return code 1!"

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pyinstaller, exe, apscheduler

I'm receiving this error when I try to launch an executable I compiled from a .py file using pyinstaller. I've tried --onefile, not doing that, with and without upx, but this problem still persists, and it appears in a popup command-line window.
The .py file works on its own like a charm so I don't think the problem's there.

Here is my code for the .py file:

```
import pywhatkit
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
import logging
import sqlalchemy

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def sendmsg():
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(xx)

executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}

job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False, 
    'max_instances': 100
}

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults)
scheduler.configure({'apscheduler.daemon': False})
scheduler.add_jobstore('sqlalchemy', url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')

scheduler.start()
```

I've excluded unnecessary information from it.

Here is a picture of the error in the popup:

[image: Error message]

The dll file is also present in my system32 folder, I've also tried copying it and placing it in other locations as well but to no avail.

I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: So to clarify, you tried both `--noupx` and `--upx-exclude=MSVCP140.dll` and that didn't fix the issue? Please show all the command line args you're passing to PyInstaller.

Comment: Yup, didn't work with either of those, nor without those arguments. My standard attempts were pretty much `pyinstaller --onefile filename` However, my most recent attempt involved this: `pyinstaller --onefile --upx-exclude=MSVCP140.dll final_whatsapp.py --key 123456 -n test -F -w --upx-dir d:\upx-3.96-win64\` and it has at least done something different. Now that popup isn't coming. Instead another, non-cmd popup arises saying: 'failed to execute script: filename, because of an unhandled exception: 'The sqlalchemy>=0.8, extra == sqlalchemy' distribution was not found and is required

Comment: I have installed sqlalchemy already so do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pyinstaller --onefile --upx-exclude=MSVCP140.dll filename --key 123456 -n test -F -w --upx-dir d:\directory_to_upx
```

This worked to fix my problem.

After this I encountered a problem where the program said that there was a problem with my sqlalchemy library.

So I then changed my last line of imports to:

```py
from flask-sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

And the last line of my code to:

```py
scheduler.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore(url))
```

Hope this helps anyone else who encounters the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this exact same error on Windows when my drive was full. **I solved it by making some space on my drive** and then running the exe file again. (I didn't need to rerun pyinstaller).

Hopefully this helps someone out. Also, I am interested to know why this error came up instead of something else. Was really confusing until I realized what was happening.